# Minimum APK size of a Chromecast sender app?

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

Is there any way to add Chromecast functionality to an Android app without dragging in so many dependencies? As far as I can tell, a sender app requires the following libraries:

- android-support-v4
- android-support-v7-appcompat
- android-support-v7-mediarouter
- GoogleCastSDK

I have created a minimal sender app. It's a single Activity that does nothing but create & dispose a CastContext. It does not use an Action Bar. The release build (using proguard-android.txt) is almost 500KB!

I intend to add Chromecast support to an already-existing video player app. The existing app is currently under 400KB, does not use any support libraries, and works perfectly on Android 2.2+.

Am I missing something here? Basically, a Chromecast sender discovers receivers using UDP and communicates with receivers using WebSockets. Why does that require multiple megabytes of JARs and resource files?

Comment: 500KB != multiple megabytes

Comment: OK, I did exaggerate a bit there. :) The size of the JARs + the appcompat resource files is about 2MB. I guess it's the forced dependency on appcompat that is really bothering me...

Comment: You don't need v4 explicitly, it is part of the v7. As for the rest, that is the dependency that you cannot get around.